# iPhone game "Paper Toss" programming physics

Tags: iphone, game-physics

I have started looking into iPhone game programming. I want to build a game similar to [Paper Toss](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/paper-toss/id317917431?mt=8) that allow users to throw a paper in given dustbin at certain distance! I am totally new and trying to research on where to start with this. What could be the physics involved in user's selected direction and where should paper land etc etc. Could anyone please get me into right direction please. Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe it's all based on Projectile Motion physics ... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uUsUaPJUc0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Physical factors involved:

1. Gravity (constant).
2. Projectile mass (probably constant), initial velocity (variable, depends on user input), and drag (constant).
3. Wind speed and direction (variable).
4. Starting location (probably constant).
5. Dustbin location (could be constant or variable).

Comment: This is great Caleb! It would be great if you could also tell me how to build parabolic path from starting and ending position? Also how to decide whether paper should go in bin or somewhere else? Moreover if you could point me some examples that I can play around that would be great help. Thanks for being there.

Comment: I think you'd be well served by a book like [*Physics for Game Developers*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000066.do). There's nothing too complex going on; for example, the vertical component will probably only depend on gravity, and the equation for that is s' = 1/2gt^2 + vt + s, where g is the gravitational constant (9.8 m/s^2), v and s are initial vertical velocity and initial position, s is position at time t. The other equations are equally simple, but you'll need to do the math in 3 dimensions (will involve some trig), which is beyond the scope of this comment.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much Caleb. That's enough for me to start and jump into Gaming programming :)

Answer (score 1):

You may also be able to benefit from an existing physics library, like Box2D. If you can get the numbers to "feel" right for the phone screen, it will handle forces (gravity, wind) and collisions (bouncing off the rim or other objects) for you. This is what I did in my "Hoops" game, which lets you shoot a basketball into a hoop.

I know someone who created a paper toss game using NME, and he was very happy with it. I created my Hoops game in a couple of days, in time for a "Hot Apps" competition that was running for webOS at the time.

The paper toss game isn't on there, but there's some screenshots for my Hoops game on this page:

http://www.haxenme.org/showcase